# ADF Essentials with GlassFish Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing an application using ADF Essentials and GlassFish Server. Is it similar to a J2EE Application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.As ADf Essentials itself is Java EE framework.

You can also integrate it with other Java EE frameworks like struts,spring.